# How to setup fisheye/crucible reviews in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, atlassian-crucible

I am trying to review a peer's code in IntelliJ Idea 15. I have been able to set-up the atlassian plugin fine in IntelliJ and I'm able to see all of the jiras and filters through the jira tab. But there is no crucible review coming up which I have manually created through a web-browser in fisheye/crucible login.  How could I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is [not supported](https://www.atlassian.com/software/ide-connectors/overview) by Atlassian anymore. And there is no development in [plugin repo](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/connector-idea) more than year.

I would expect that some features will stop working as soon as Atlassian update APIs. It is like ticking bomb - with any update of service plugin can become incompatible.